# Storing products in session with zend

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, namespaces

how you add products in session with zend? I receive products as an array

i try this, but dont work

aand how u take this session in another action...

thnx a lot

```
 public function incartAction(){
     $this->_helper->_layout->disableLayout();        
    $id = $this->_getParam("id");
    $name= $this->_getParam("name");
    $price= $this->getParam("price");
    $img = $this->_getParam("img");
    $qty = $this->_getParam("qty");

    $produs = array(
      "id"=>$id,
      "name"=>$name,
      "price"=>$price,
      "img"=>$img,
      "qty"=>$qty
    );        
    $produs_model = new Application_Model_DbTable_Produs;
    $produs_model->updateProdusById($id, $qty);

    $cart = new Zend_Session_Namespace("products");
    $cart->products->$name= $product;

    $this->view->assign("cart", $cart);        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are doing it wrong and you have a mistake in variable name also,

Here is how you can do it,

first define it in some controller,

```
public function incartAction(){
    $product = array(
             "id"=>$id,
             "name"=>$name,
             "price"=>$price,
             "img"=>$img,
             "qty"=>$qty
            );  


//add it to session variable [in same controller]

     $cart = new Zend_Session_Namespace("products");
     $cart->product= $product;
}
```

now use it in another controller,

```
public function outcartAction(){
     $cart = new Zend_Session_Namespace("products");
     $product= $cart->product;
     print_r($product);
}
```

Comment: thnx dude ... I correct my mistakes last night, now all its fine :)